Is it possible to prove the difference of these functions is monotonic?
This is the last part of a project I need to finish a proof I've been working on over the summer. I know I should try to find a potential solution before I post here, but I haven't been able to make progress over the past few days, so any help is appreciated :)
$$f(x) = \frac{\\N(p_x)}{\phi(N(p_x))}$$
$$g(x) = e^y\ln(\ln(N(p_x)))$$
Where $\phi(x)$ is Euler's totient function, $p_x$ is the $x$th prime, and $N(x)$ is the primorial. The domain of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are expanded to the real numbers by defining them in any way such that
$f(x)$ is between $f(\text{floor}(x))$ and $f(\text{ceiling}(x))$
and $g(x)$ is between $g(\text{floor}(x))$ and $g(\text{ceiling}(x))$
$f(x) > g(x)$
As $x$ goes to infinity:
$f(x)$ and $g(x)$ go to infinity
$f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$ go to 0
$f(x)-g(x)$ goes to 0
These are well-known limits related to Robin's theory and by extension the Riemann hypothesis.
Is there any way to prove $f(x)-g(x)$ is monotonic?
Or more specifically, is there any way to find the domain in which $f(x) - g(x) > c;$ for any constant $c > 0$?
EDIT: Clarity
EDIT 2: Here's a graph showing it's monotonic for the first 46 primes: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lj50xixn6u
P.S. If either one of my conditions is true, there's a chance counterexamples of Robin's inequality are within a well-defined region!

Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. Where does this question come from? Why do you think that $f - g$ could be monotonic?

Difference of monotonic functions need not be monotonic. E.g., take $f(x)=x$, and $g(x)=2x$ if $x\leq 0$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{2}x$ for $x\gt0$. Then $f-g$ is $-x$ for $x\leq 0$, which is decreasing, and $\frac{1}{2}x$ for $x\gt 0$, which is increasing.

@Hans Over the past month I've made a proof that all natural numbers can be  divided into categories that show that theres a well defined and possibly finite region where counter examples of Robin's inequality exist, but only if there's a finite amount of times f(x) - g(x) > c. I've updated my request with more context and empirical evidence.

@arturo I've updated my question, there's two specific functions I'm asking about, not monotonic functions in general. Thanks for the clarification though!

For general functions $f$ and $g$ satisfying the listed properties  the conclusion does not hold.
I assume the functions are defined on $[1,\infty).$ Let  $$ f(x)=\sqrt{x}-{1\over x+2}, \ g(x)=\sqrt{x}-{1\over x+\cos x}$$ Then $f(x)>g(x).$  The functions $f$ and $g$ are increasing as their derivatives are positive. We have $f'(x),\ g'(x)\to 0$ and $f(x)-g(x)\to 0$ when $x\to \infty.$
We have  $$f(x)-g(x)= {2-\cos x\over (x+\cos x)(x+1)}$$ Moreover $$ f(2\pi n)-g(2\pi n)\approx {1\over 4\pi^2n^2}\\ f(2\pi n+\pi)-g(2\pi n+\pi)\approx {3\over 4\pi^2n^2}$$
Thus the function $h:=f-g$ is not monotonic on any interval $[a,\infty)$  as $$h(2\pi n)<h(2\pi n+\pi)>h(2\pi n+2\pi)$$ for large values of $n.$
The functions $f$ and $g$ can be easily extended to positive increasing functions on the whole real line so that $f(x)>g(x).$
